# update flag value with hiddenfield value in static method

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

**Javascript**

```
function btnNewPatientClick()
        {
            hidFlag.value = "false";}
function btnExistingPatient_Click()
        {
            hidFlag.value = "true";}
```

**ASPX..**

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPatientID" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" CssClass="csstextbox"
                                    runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span class="csstexterror">*</span>
                                <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="txtPatientID_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" ServiceMethod="GetPatientID"
                                    MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionSetCount="1" TargetControlID="txtPatientID"
                                    UseContextKey="True" DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True">
                                </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

**C#**

```
 static string flag = "";
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    flag = hidFlag.Value;
 }

 [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
 public static string[] GetPatientID(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
 {
     if(flag == "true"){
        ///code to get patientID
     }
 }
```

I have two buttons NEW Patinet,Existing Patinet and one textbox 
For selection of Patinet name Used autocompleteExtender of ajax toolkit. If i click on new student button then i dont allow to populate students in textbox and if click on Existing student then allow to populate students in textbox.I have set flag but fails what is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1)Take button in update panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdatePanel" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpdatePanel_Click" Style="display: none;" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdatePanel" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

2)call update panel button click from javascript.

```
function btnNewPatientClick()
        {hidFlag.value = "false";
            btnUpdatePanel.click();
//rest of ur code...}
```

3)on server side button click change flag value with hiddenFiled value.

```
protected void btnUpdatePanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flag = hidFlag.Value;
    }
```

It should work tested...

Answer (score 0):

you cant access controls in Ajax call. for more information 
read this

1. [Ajax and Page Controls](http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/)

Comment: what about update flag value with hiddenfiled value in static method